# Contour plot with 2 arrays and a third containing chi-squared in python

Tags: python, scipy, contour

I have the chi-squared for all values of:

```
kT=linspace(0.01,0.11,10)
v=linspace(0.05,0.5,10)

where:

KT=[]
V=[]
for i in range(len(kT)):
    for u in range(len(v)):
        KT.append(kT[i])
        V.append(v[u])
```

Therefore I have:

```
KT=asarray(KT)
V=asarray(V)
x=asarray(x)
```

Where `x[0]` is the chi-squared for `(kT[0],v[0])`,
and `x[1]` is the chi-squared for `(kT[0],v[1])`

etc...

So as an overview, I have 1D arrays of `len=100`, where `kT[0]` and `v[0]` gives `x[0]` (this is done in another program).

I want to plot the chi-squared as a contour plot, how do I go about this? I tried using the contour from plt.contour, but it was x as a 2D vector.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reshape` your array

```
x2d = x.reshape(10, 10)
```

`contour` accepts vectors for grid coordinates. you can therefore omit the double loop and use `kT` and `v` directly

```
pyplot.contour(v, kT, x2d)
```